# Grammar rule implementation in java

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I need some logic to find a grammatical pattern like in a sentence:

```
[adjective]* [noun]+ [hyphen] [verb Past Participle | verb Present Participle | one of the special adjectives] [adjective]* [noun]+
```

where * means any number (0 or more), ? means 0 or 1, and + means 1 or more, | means or.

If i give any input sentence the logic has to search if it contains the above pattern or not.
I completely have no idea how to begin.
Please if anyone could suggest me with some logic.

Comment: does your input contain word type information? (i.e. how are you planning to classify words as adj/noun/etc?, if it is not part of the input)? using a 3rd party dictionary, perhaps?

Comment: The situation fits to be handled by regex

Comment: @Ibrahim I have defined the word type information manually in the program. I do not need a third party dictionary right now.

Comment: It can also be handled by implementing language recognition parser such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) or [javacc](http://javacc.java.net)

Comment: @2012-EndoftheWorld I need only logic rather than API. I want to implement it logically without any third party.

Comment: @Suneeta Singh You need logic for only one pattern, or you want to write spell checker with full functionality? If you need full functionality - you have to use chunk parsing (`adjective` example: "cat", `adjective chunk` example: "a black cat with brown eyes"). So this is not so simple... (see my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pseudo code. It makes 2 passes on the input, in the first pass it converts each word in the input string to a letter which refers to its type, and on the second pass you match the result of the first pass with your regular expression.

```
method(input) {
    typed_input = '';
    for (word in input) {
        if (word is noun) {
            typed_input += 'n'
        else if (word is adjective)
            typed_input += 'a'
        else if (word is hyphen)
            typed_input += 'h'
        else if (word is verb Past Participle)
            typed_input += 'v'
        else if (word is verb Present Participle)
            typed_input += 'p'
        else if (word is one of the special adjectives)
            typed_input += 's'
        else
           throw exception("invalid input")
    }
    return typed_input.match("a*n+h[v|p|s]a*n+")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I guess it is going to help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatical pattern you wrote is very simple and not practical. You should use chunk parsing. Adjective in sentence may be not only one word (like "cat"), it may be a chunk of words (like "black cat with brown eyes").

Your pattern will fail when sentence will contain "chunk" instead of single adjective. Sentences should be parsed like tree structure.

Grammar checking is pretty complicated problem. **Before you write anything - you should get familiar with theory about grammar checking and natural language processing.**

You may start with this:

[Developing a Chunk-based Grammar Checker for Translated English Sentences
by Nay Yee Lina, Khin Mar Soeb and Ni Lar Thein](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Y11-1026.pdf)

and maybe this too:

[A Grammar Correction Algorithm Deep Parsing and Minimal Corrections for a Grammar Checker
by Lionel Clément, Kim Gerdes, Renaud Marlet](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/39/62/40/PDF/FG2009-Clement-et-al.pdf)

[SCP: A Simple Chunk Parser by Philip Brooks](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/pronto/Brooks.pdf)

I could put this in comment, but titles are long and here it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you. [Link to standford parser.](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp)
Also You can download the code in java.

Answer (score 0):

I have written simler program in java using stand ford parser.You should generate tagged word of array list using java stand ford parser.

```
 package postagger;
    /*
     * 
     * 
     * lphabetical list of part-of-speech tags used in the Penn Treebank Project:

    Number
    Tag
    Description
    1.  CC  Coordinating conjunction
    2.  CD  Cardinal number
    3.  DT  Determiner
    4.  EX  Existential there
    5.  FW  Foreign word
    6.  IN  Preposition or subordinating conjunction
    7.  JJ  Adjective
    8.  JJR Adjective, comparative
    9.  JJS Adjective, superlative
    10. LS  List item marker
    11. MD  Modal
    12. NN  Noun, singular or mass
    13. NNS Noun, plural
    14. NNP Proper noun, singular
    15. NNPS    Proper noun, plural
    16. PDT Predeterminer
    17. POS Possessive ending
    18. PRP Personal pronoun
    19. PRP$    Possessive pronoun
    20. RB  Adverb
    21. RBR Adverb, comparative
    22. RBS Adverb, superlative
    23. RP  Particle
    24. SYM Symbol
    25. TO  to
    26. UH  Interjection
    27. VB  Verb, base form
    28. VBD Verb, past tense
    29. VBG Verb, gerund or present participle
    30. VBN Verb, past participle
    31. VBP Verb, non-3rd person singular present
    32. VBZ Verb, 3rd person singular present
    33. WDT Wh-determiner
    34. WP  Wh-pronoun
    35. WP$ Possessive wh-pronoun
    36. WRB Wh-adverb
     */
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.StringReader;

    import semanticengine.Description;


    import edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.TokenizerFactory;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.process.CoreLabelTokenFactory;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;  
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;  
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.TaggedWord;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;

    public class EnglishParser {
    public    static LexicalizedParser lp = null;

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {



          EnglishParser MC=new EnglishParser();
          Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
          String s="";
          while(s!="end")
          {
          s=sc.nextLine();
          ArrayList<TaggedWord> AT=MC.Parse(s);
          Description obj=   new  Description(AT );

          System.out.println (AT);
          }


      }



    public static void demoDP(LexicalizedParser lp, String filename) {
        // This option shows loading and sentence-segment and tokenizing
        // a file using DocumentPreprocessor
        TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
        GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
        // You could also create a tokenier here (as below) and pass it
        // to DocumentPreprocessor
        for (List<HasWord> sentence : new DocumentPreprocessor(filename)) {
          Tree parse = lp.apply(sentence);
          parse.pennPrint();
          System.out.println();

          GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
          Collection tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed(true);
          System.out.println(tdl);
          System.out.println();
        }
      }










      //Method for Pos taging.(POS) tagger that assigns its class
      //(verb, adjective, ...) to each word of the sentence,
      //para@ english is the argument to be tagged
      public ArrayList<TaggedWord> Parse(String English)
      { 
          String[] sent =English.split(" ");// { "This", "is", "an", "easy", "sentence", "." };
          List<CoreLabel> rawWords = new ArrayList<CoreLabel>();
          for (String word : sent) {
              CoreLabel l = new CoreLabel();
              l.setWord(word);
              rawWords.add(l);
                }
      Tree parse = lp.apply(rawWords);
      return parse.taggedYield();

      }










      public EnglishParser() 
      {
          lp = 
                  new LexicalizedParser("grammar/englishPCFG.ser.gz");


      } // static methods only

    }


    // return pattern of the sentence
        public String getPattern(ArrayList<TaggedWord> Sen) 
{
            Iterator<TaggedWord> its = Sen.iterator();
            while (its.hasNext()) {
                TaggedWord obj = its.next();
                if ((obj.tag().equals("VBZ")) || (obj.tag().equals("VBP"))) {
                    if (its.hasNext()) {
                        TaggedWord obj2 = its.next();

                        if (obj2.tag().equals("VBG")) {
                            if (its.hasNext()) {
                                TaggedWord obj3 = its.next();
                                if ((obj3.tag().equals("VBN"))) {
                                    return "PRESENT_CONT_PASS";

                                }
                            }
                            return "PRESENT_CONT";
                            // Present Continues
                        } else if ((obj2.tag().equals("VBN"))) {
                            return "PRESENT_PASS";

                        }
                        return "PRESENT_SIMP";

                    } else {
                        return "PRESENT_SIMP";
                    }

                } else if (obj.tag().equals("VBD")) {
                    if (its.hasNext()) {
                        TaggedWord obj2 = its.next();

                        if (obj2.tag().equals("VBG")) {

                            if (its.hasNext()) {
                                TaggedWord obj3 = its.next();
                                if ((obj3.tag().equals("VBN"))) {
                                    return "PATT_CONT_PASS";

                                }
                            }

                            return "PAST_CONT";
                        } else if ((obj2.tag().equals("VBN"))) {
                            return "PAST_PASS";

                        }
                        return "PAST_SIMP";

                    } else {
                        return "PAST_SIMP";
                    }

                }

                else if (obj.tag().equals("VB")) {
                    if (its.hasNext()) {
                        TaggedWord obj2 = its.next();

                        if (obj2.tag().equals("VBG")) {
                            return "FUT_CONT";
                        } else if ((obj2.tag().equals("VBN"))) {
                            return "FUT_CONT";

                        }

                    } else {
                        return "FUT_SIMP";
                    }

                }

            }
            return "NO_PATTERN";
        }
```